# How do I denote an object in a sentence?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to say "Can you clone X?"
So far I've gotten this sentence:

> 복제 할 수 있어요?

Which to me sounds like "Can you clone?" But what I really want to say is, `Can you clone X?`

Comment: Welcome. I changed the title to be more specific - feel free to edit if you don't think it's what you meant.

Answer (score 6):

Simply put the object with objective particle.

> X를 복제할 수 있어요?

Or you can use sort-of passive form by placing X at the subject, depending on the focus of the question.

> X가 복제되요?

In this case, you are asking the possibility of X being cloned, while the first asking about the listener's capability of cloning X.